# Syntax error in python3.7 site packages python_utils/converters.py

Tags: syntax-error, conda, environment

```
File "~/anaconda3/envs/posydon-conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/python_utils/converters.py", line 89
    if match := regexp.search(input_):
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have the above error when importing a package in ipython in a conda environment, and couldn't figure out what's wrong. I'm using linux.

I have checked that which python in the environment point to the correct python and the python version is indeed 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

In the error message you can [a walrus operator `:=`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) is being used, which is a Python 3.8 feature. Also, if you check the requirements on the [PyPi page](https://pypi.org/project/python-utils/), you can see they state "Requires: Python >3.8.0".

What you need to do is upgrade you Python to 3.8.*, if you want to use that pacakge.